# Using Qt Creator to Open CMakeLists.txt, and how to save as a .pro file?

Tags: qt, cmake

The Qt creator can open CMakeLists.txt as a project. But when I opened the project in Qt Creator, how to save it to a .pro file for the next time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QMake and CMake are two different build systems, there's no fool-proof conversion between them that could be done automatically. There are some helper tools for QMake to CMake, but they don't guarantee a fully working result. I am not aware of any automatic conversion from CMake to QMake. (Usually one converts from QMake to CMake, as CMake is vastly more powerful; although the CMake support in Qt Creator isn't that good, unfortunately).

I'd suggest to stick with CMake.

Comment: Thank you. I can't agree with you any more. I am just familiar with QT Creator, I open a CMakeList.txt ,then it is converted to a qt project, But I want to save the opened project into a .pro, so that the next time I  don't have to set several CMake variables.

Comment: A .pro file is a QMake file, so "saving to a .pro file" is equivalent with "convert to QMake".

Comment: @Zhong I've not used CMake with QtC, but any such settings are stored in `project.pro.user` when using a `project.pro` file. Are you sure that file (with that or different name) does not get created when you use a CMake project?

Comment: @hyde, thanks, sir. I have used the Qt Creator to load CMake projects. Firstly, I use CMake-gui to generate cmake temporary files in a directory named `build`. Then use Qt Creator to open the CMakeFiles.txt, then the Qt Creator let to select the build directory. Then select the `build` directory, then the whold cmake project will be loaded into the Qt Creator IDE. If you don't delete the `build` directory, you can load the project next time without need to generate the cmake temporary files again.

Comment: CMake support in Qt Creator isnt good, and you suggest to stick with it?

Comment: @AndersLindén: IDE support is one of the criteria for the choice of build system, but by far not the only one. To judge which one is better suited one would know more about the project. As the OP was opening an existing CMakeLists.txt, that suggests that there already is a build system and that it might not be the user's choice to migrate away from it. And managing multiple build systems in parallel is probably the worst option.